# MySQL. Grouping by parameter that was calculated using FLOOR() produce duplicated values

Tags: mysql, floor

I am using the following query:

```
Select 
    count(a), 
    floor(b/c) as parameter
from table
group by parameter;
```

And it produces the result with the duplicate values in the column I used for grouping. Something like this:

```
count(a)    parameter
5           0
3           0
1           1
4           2
1           2
```

It seems like it groups by (b/c) and not by FLOOR(b/c). Does anyone know the way around it?
And also if someone can explaing why it is happening, that would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Could you provide a schema definition with example data inserts? Like here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sZABrWqmD22kz9tgPoZX65/0 As you can see for this schema and example data your query returns a correct result.

Comment: Also your mysql version number.